# SELECT para preencher um campo

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Boa tarde, possuo uma tabela chamada `Pessoa` e outra `Matricula`, eu preciso fazer uma consulta que me retorne os campos **nome**, **matricula** e **seq_pessoa** delas, onde **nome** e **seq_pessoa** estão na tabela `Pessoa` e matricula na tabela `Matricula` para retornar em select que a cada letra informada vai buscar no BD passando as letras informadas.

---

#### Exemplo 1

Ele vai fazendo a consulta conforme vai inserindo as letras.

[image: exemplo 1]

Esse select esta da seguinte maneira, esta funcionando para o que precisa em outro campo.

```
SELECT seq_pessoa AS id
                 , UPPER(nome) AS text
              FROM pessoa
             WHERE nome ILIKE '%". $nome ."%'
```

---

### Duvida

Porém agora tenho o seguinte select que não esta funcionando corretamente

```
SELECT m.matricula AS id
                 , UPPER(p.nome) AS text
              FROM matricula as m
              JOIN pessoas as p USING (seq_pessoa)
```

O que eu preciso é ao invés de informar o nome do usuário, informar o código de matricula e ele me retornar o nome dele.

Comment: Como a tabela `matricula` e `pessoas` se ligam? Qual a chave estrangeira?

Comment: @PedroPaulo PK da tabela `Pessoa` é a `seq_pessoa`, ela que liga a `Matricula`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT m.matricula AS id
                 , UPPER(p.nome) AS text
              FROM matricula as m
              JOIN pessoas as p USING (seq_pessoa)
WHERE m.matricula = matricula
```

Lembrando que a variável matricula deve ser informada, tal como foi informado no código de exemplo a variável $nome.

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava, muito obrigado.